# Incorrect application version found on all instances. Expected version

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Good day, I hosted my Laravel application on AWS Beanstalk, through the console, the earlier versions are working because I have deployed other versions before and they worked, however, I deployed today and my health check is reading degraded, when I opened the health check, I am seeing

**Incorrect application version "Sample Application-10" (deployment 9). Expected version "Sample Application-14" (deployment 17).**

please, is there a way to resolve this without rebooting my environment

Comment: Have you inspected any EB logs to possibly identify why  Sample Application-14 failed to deploy?

Comment: I tried requesting for logs, but it is not bringing it up

Comment: Can you ssh into the EB instance, and check from inside. They should be in `/var/logs`

Comment: I am using the console, I can't ssh

Answer (score 0):

If you are **using the NodeJS app**, delete the package-lock.json file and node_modules folder. Reinstall all packages with ***"npm i"*** and redeploy with ***"eb deploy"***.